# Using spring mongodb 1.6.0.RELEASE in grails

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, grails, groovy

I'm using `grails 2.3.7` for my web application and `mongoDB` for data store. I have full text search enabled for few fields in a collection. I'm using `spring-data-mongodb-1.6.0.RELEASE's TextCriteria` to do this. But when I use it in grails, I get an error:

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the
>   application:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@2fd477a0
>   has not been refreshed yet. Message:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@2fd477a0
>   has not been refreshed yet.

I'm not getting any more information from logs. This is all I see even if I set log level to debug. It is an issue with `1.6.0.RELEASE` only. It works fine with lower versions. But `TextCriteria` is available only in `1.6.0.RELEASE`. So I dont have any option but to use this version. Any clues what might be the issue?

Comment: are you using the mongo plugin and overriding the deps or are you using spring-data-mongodb directly?

Comment: I'm using spring-data-mongodb directly

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when you have "spring" dependencies that require different versions of spring.  Please see:  https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!msg/vcap-dev/ixuMoCT2tlM/aLtEdZhRPTEJ